# MaterialDatePicker : how to set custom today

Tags: android, material-design, android-datepicker, material-components, material-components-android

I want to set custom today to the `MaterialDatePicker`. 
But it getting the system date by default. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment. This answer doesn't solve your question but just explains why it is not possible to do it.

Currently (`1.1.0-beta02` and `1.2.0-alpha02`) you **can't** customize the **value** of the `today`.
In the adapter used by the [`MaterialDatePicker`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0-beta02/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/MonthAdapter.java#L139) you can check:

> ```
> if (UtcDates.getTodayCalendar().getTimeInMillis() == date) {
>     calendarStyle.todayDay.styleItem(day);
>     //..
>   } else {
>     calendarStyle.day.styleItem(day);
>     //..
>   }
> ```

You can customize the **style** used by the `Day.Today`.

```
 <style name="CustomThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar"
       parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar" >
   <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/CustomWidget_MaterialCalendar</item>
 </style>

 <style name="CustomWidget_MaterialCalendar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="dayTodayStyle">@style/CustomWidget_DayToday</item>
  </style>

  <style name="CustomWidget_DayToday" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Day.Today">
     <item name="itemTextColor">@color/...</item>
     <item name="itemStrokeColor">@color/...</item>
  </style>
```